# Pandas ExcelWriter Openpyxl append mode corrupts Excel file

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl, pandas.excelwriter

Using pandas excelwriter append mode (engine=openpyxl) corrupts my excel file.

I've read through prior versions of this issue, and can confirm that in my version of pandas/openpyxl

```
self.handles.handle.seek(0)
self.handles.handle.truncate()
```

is in the file. Here is my code, which adds some data to an existing excel sheet:

```
file_name = 'AA Tracker.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name,engine='openpyxl',if_sheet_exists='overlay', mode='a')
dfq.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=ticker,startrow=startrow , startcol=0)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

While this produces the desired result, the excel file gets corrupted:

[image]

The file is not able to be opened in Excel 365, but somehow in Excel 2016 I can repair the file and see that the result is what I expect. Oddly when I save this file after repair, it prompts me to save over the old file instead of simply saving, not sure if that's a clue...

In any case, this must work in 365, any ideas?

My package versions:

```
pandas 1.4.1
openpyxl 3.0.9
python 3.9.7
```

Comment: What happens if you just open and save the file (with a different name!) in openpyxl?